# one function that checks if any of the service's http failed

Tags: angular

I have many services in my app and many http request.
I want to show alert to user that there was problem with api connection in the alert box, but i dont want to edit each http funcion in each service. Can I do this in one place?

Comment: [With an interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#advanced-usage) if you're using `HttpClient`, by subclassing or wrapping `Http` and injecting your own version if you're not. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43104627/centralized-handling-for-http-errors-in-angular-4, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929046/generic-http-error-handling-in-angular for examples of the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Interceptors](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses)** are the way to go. But you will have to use the new `HttpClient` instead of the old, soon-to-be deprecated `Http`.

Something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorHandlerService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next
      .handle(req)
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('HTTP error occured');
        return Observable.throw(err);
      });
  }

}
```

Comment: I've injected it before other services, but your interceptor does not log error. it logs only: https://imgur.com/a/fOvIp

Comment: I don't have access to images (corporate proxy), and it's usually not recommended to upload your errors as images on SOF. Could you show the trace directly to me please ? And did you inject your interceptor as the tutorial asks you to ?

Comment: i've figuret it out already., thank you. could you show me example how to listen to it for example in some alert component?

Comment: Well, you could use the **[Snackbar from Angular material](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview)**, this is what I do and it's very easy to use (all the tutorials are in this site) !